# Is modal service deleted and not changed for any new service?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a question, recently I have upgrade a project of Spartacus from version 4 to 5 and something that I saw is that Modal Service seams to be deleted from version 5, but I do not find any new service that could be used instead and also I do not find any specific upgrade documentation talking about this. Can someone let me know what is going on ? If we will not use Modal Service in any new version or if there is an alternative for it.

Thanks

Use Modal Service when upgrading to spartacus 5

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly mentioned in the SAP documentation you can check this:

[remove all of model service](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/10a8bc7f635b4e3db6f6bb7880e58a7d/7266f6f01edb4328b4e09df299ea09be.html?version=5.0#removal-of-modalservice-and-related-code)

URL:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/10a8bc7f635b4e3db6f6bb7880e58a7d/7266f6f01edb4328b4e09df299ea09be.html?version=5.0#removal-of-modalservice-and-related-code

Note: if you try to replace with ng-boostrap than might be you will get an error: **CmsComponentData**